# Why can't I gain access to my homepage images?

Tags: images, homepage, frontpage

Site: https://burgessroad.org/. WordPress version: 6.0

I inherited maintenance responsibilities for the site and I need to replace some images on the homepage and alter positioning of others because logos and fonts that identify the church are changing. However, I don't know how to get access to the images.
There was a time when I could make changes to the HTML code directly to affect how images appear, but, with WordPress 6.0 that's no longer possible. Maybe one solution is to select the homepage in the Pages tab in the admin area, except "Homepage" is not shown in the Pages list. Another solution might be to use Appearance > Additional CSS, except that option gives no access to any images, only two menu lists (footer-left & footer-middle). In addition, I'm not well versed on CSS and though I've checked several sites for CSS syntax usage and the kinds of image identifiers that are needed, I get no success trying to alter homepage images by applying "my" CSS in the Additional CSS edit area.  So -------
Where is my homepage?
How can I find my homepage?
How can I access the images (for replacement or positioning changes) on my homepage?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go look under SETTINGS > READING and see which page is listed as your 'Homepage:'.  
A lot of what you're asking is theme specific - and the theme itself may have options to make these adjustments or perhaps they're hard coded... ...hard to tell without seeing code from within the theme.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.